# Using Gulp to split SASS/CSS file into multiple CSS files based on media queries?

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

Optimize a website *without implementing render based optimizations*. **The solution would need to be using gulp** so that we can perform the task during testing and deployment.

Is there an open source library for gulp that allows us to split a single CSS file into multiple CSS files based on their media queries? Alternatively, is there a library that can perform this split from SASS while outputting the different CSS files as opposed to a single one?

> Below is an example version of a source CSS file that needs to be split.

```
body {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
@media(min-width: 780px){
    .whatever{
        max-width:100%
    }
}
@media(min-width: 576px){
    .col-sm{
        flex-basis:0;
        flex-grow:1;
        max-width:100%
    }
}
@media(min-width: 768px){
    .col-md{
        flex-basis:0;
        flex-grow:1;
        max-width:100%
    }
    .col-md-auto{
        flex:0 0 auto;
        width:auto;
        max-width:100%
    }
}
.footer {
    background: blue;
}
```

> The desired outcome would be to have 3 files being generated as follow:

css-critical.css

```
body {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
.footer {
    background: blue;
}
```

css-min-576.css

```
@media(min-width: 576px){
    .col-sm{
        flex-basis:0;
        flex-grow:1;
        max-width:100%
    }
}
```

css-min-780.css

```
@media(min-width: 780px){
    .whatever{
        max-width:100%
    }
    .col-md{
        flex-basis:0;
        flex-grow:1;
        max-width:100%
    }
    .col-md-auto{
        flex:0 0 auto;
        width:auto;
        max-width:100%
    }
}
```

> This will allow loading the CSS files in the HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css-critical.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css-min-576.css" media="(min-width: 576px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css-min-780.css" media="(min-width: 780px)" />
```

**IMPORTANT**: we do not pay much attention that the "css-critical.css" would not necessarily be the utmost minimum critical CSS for the given page that would be using this technique.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for but something to keep in mind is, the optimization you gain bundle size is likely to be completely lost by adding more network requests. It could even end up as a net negative overall.

Comment: First of you don't need Gulp, there are tons of others that basically do the same like rollup, webpack and parcel. These might be better, more up-to-date and more up to the task than Gulp as well. Second as mentioned by others splitting CSS might end up being worse than bundling them together

Comment: The idea is to have 4 files, one critical, plus one mobile, one tablet and one desktop. Service worker managed caching with cdn caching etc. can help negate the negative effect from the multiple requests.

Comment: We want to use gulp as we do not want to keep processing CSS styles on the fly for each page. Thank you for mentioning those negative consequences. The main CSS file is generated from SASS via gulp.

Comment: With webpack you can have multiple entry files. This with if statements in sass you can make the 4 files you need

Answer (score 4):

So there are multiple gulp plugins that can help with your task:

1. [gulp-extract-media-queries](https://github.com/unlight/gulp-extract-media-queries) has almost no settings, but creates multiple css files accordingly to your media queries. Wasn't updated for a few years, so use it carefully.
2. [gulp-split-media-queries](https://github.com/ftshp/gulp-split-media-queries) has **1** setting, that helps to extract all media queries `above` the breakpoint you put in plugin settings.
3. [gulp-media-queries-splitter](https://github.com/WebWhales/gulp-media-queries-splitter) has a lot of settings, and you can apply custom filenames for extracted css-files, `which can be helpfull if you maintain front-end and back-end parts of application`.

If you want maximum options = then number (3) is your choice, if you just wanna more simple settings = then go with (2)

Comment: Thanks for contributing @ve1ikiy, will try those and give some feedback later on when I am free. On first sight it looks very promising!